# LookUpEdit looses its value after lost focus event

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

DevExpress LookUpEdit control looses its value right after loosing it's focus.

How does one persist its value?

Comment: LookUpEdit doesn't loose its value without either the datasource is empty, or you somehow manage to clear it in code. maybe you try to bind  it in the wrong event ?

Comment: Thx for edit. Agreed. It's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find answer elsewhere ... Just wanted to share it.
(worked for my LookUpEdit, maybe it's the same for Combo)

In my case, when defining the binding to the object source, if the source property is nullable, then it has to be defined like this :

```
myLookUpOrCombo.DataBindings.Clear();
myLookUpOrCombo.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", myObjectSource, "IdOfaForeignKey", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null);
```

Otherwise event goes sort of awkward.